# Replacing Atmega8a pu 1440 arduino Ic with 1337

Tags: arduino-uno

I have one Arduino uno, and one atmega8a 1337 ic. Can i replace the Arduino uno ic with 1337 to program the 1337 one?

Comment: That second number is the date code. 40th week of 2014 vs. 37th week of 2013. They're the same chip (although they may be different revisions).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks man. I had no idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bootloader installed on the 8A then yes, you can.  The two chips are pin and electrically compatible.

Comment: How do I check for it? Sorry but I am new to this.

Comment: Did you buy it with a bootloader installed, or did you install a bootloader? If the answer to both those is no then you will need to install a bootloader. You can use your existing Arduino Uno to do it - google for tutorials, there's plenty.